# Are reactively declared img alt tags detrimental for SEO?

Tags: vue.js, seo, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

If instead of declaring the `alt` tag like so:

```html
<img src="..." alt="banana">
```

I declare it in a vue component that gets rendered only when the user opens its url:

```html
<template>
    <img src="..." alt="state.alt">
</template>


<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue"

const state = reactive({
    alt: 'banana'
})
```

will it negatively impact `SEO`/`site crawlers` in their ability of portraing my site in search results?

Answer (score 0):

If your website is Server Side Rendered or Server Side Generated, you will get the full benefits of SEO. Otherwise, you will get some from a simpler SPA, but it will not be as good ([Google Chrome Developers](https://www.youtube.com/c/GoogleChromeDevelopers/videos) have some resources on that subject, it's not that hard to find anyway).

Frameworks like [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) or [Nuxt3](https://github.com/nuxt/framework) can help you with that.
Also, there are some services that may render your SPA statically, but it's not as good as the 2 solutions listed above.